# CORS Header Access-Control-Allow-Origin wildcard failing after successives

Tags: jquery, wildcard, cors

I have two endpoints, a www and an api.  The API drives backbone.js collections and this has so far run without a hitch.  A new RPC enpoint is failing a Access-Control-Allow-Origin CORS check, but I don't know how to debug.  Several preflight OPTIONS calls from the website are successful in returning a result-set, however this new one is failing outright.  The new RPC which is failing is manually fired by a button click.  It does not exist within an iframe or any container with a weird security scope.  All this is happening in the same web page.

I have 3 calls for certain collections, with request/response as follows :

**Request** :

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, authorization, origin
Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
```

**Response**:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:X-Requested-With,Authorization,Accept,Origin,Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:2
Content-Type:text/plain
Date:Tue, 26 Feb 2013 01:53:33 GMT
Server:nginx/1.1.19
X-Frame-Options:DENY
X-Powered-By:Express
```

^^ Victory! All collections are populating.  I can GET/POST/PUT/DELETE models in these collections with impunity.

The call that is failing :

### OPTIONS (preflight)

**Request**:

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, origin, authorization, content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Host:api.bip.io
Origin:https://bip.io
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:https://bip.io/dash/account
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko Chrome/24.0.1312.52 Safari/537.17
```

**Response**:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:X-Requested-With,Authorization,Accept,Origin,Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:2
Content-Type:text/plain
Date:Tue, 26 Feb 2013 01:55:26 GMT
Server:nginx/1.1.19
X-Frame-Options:DENY
X-Powered-By:Express
```

### GET Request

```
GET /rpc/domain/confirm/55e648b5-1098-41e8-9d76-bd020ebe6d37

Request URL:https://api.bip.io/rpc/domain/confirm/55e648b5-1098-41e8-9d76-bd020ebe6d37
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Authorization:Basic {XX-OBFUSCATED}
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Type:application/json
Origin:https://bip.io
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:https://bip.io/dash/account
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.52 Safari/537.17
```

The Chrome Error for the last request is :

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.bip.io/rpc/domain/confirm/55e648b5-1098-41e8-9d76-bd020ebe6d37. 
Origin https://bip.io is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

All of these calls get funneled through this jQuery v1.8.2 method :

```
//  request handler
    _request : function(payload, methodAPI, methodHTTP, onSuccess, onFail) {
        var self = this;
        var payload = null == payload ? payload : JSON.stringify(payload);

        var reqStruct = {
            type: methodHTTP,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: methodAPI,
            success: function(resData, status, xhr) {
                if (undefined != onSuccess) {
                    onSuccess(resData, payload);
                }
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, errText) {
                if (undefined !== onFail) {
                    onFail(xhr.status, status, errText, payload);
                }
            }
        };

        if (null !== payload) {
            reqStruct.data = payload;
        }

        $.ajax(reqStruct);
    }
```

How to debug?? Thanks!

Comment: Can you view the requests in the Chrome debugger's "Network" tab? Are there any additional headers on the failing request that may be missed by the preflight? You can also try using the http://test-cors.org to recreate your request and try to find the proper preflight response.

Comment: There's no additional headers other than what's been posted for that OPTIONS/GET pair, unfortunately.  I hadn't heard of test-cors.org though however, will check it out thankyou

Comment: I think you need to explicitly set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:https://api.bip.io`, not use a wildcard.

Comment: Solved.  The issue was actually server side.  Preflight was passing because the OPTIONS method was explicitly being caught for CORS.  The subsequent request-method handler was sending partial headers back.

You MUST send the same CORS headers back with both OPTIONS preflight and its subsequent request.